# Why does i'm have Problem with Graphic Glitchs Drawing

Tags: c++, graphics, visual-glitch

I'm tired to make a joke virus that makes Graphics "glitches". (Note: this code is in C++.)
Here is Code:

```
#include <windows.h>




int main(){
    
            HDC hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
            POINT wPt[3];
            RECT wRect;
    int x = GetSystemMetrics(0), y = GetSystemMetrics(1);
    
    while (TRUE)
    {
        int c = 10
        ;GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &wRect);
        WPT[0].x = wRect.left + rand() % 21 - 11;
        WPt[0].x = wRect.bottom + rand() % 21 - 11;
        WPt[0].x = wRect.right + rand() % 21 - 11;
        WPt[0].x = wRect.top + rand() % 10 - 5;
        WPt[0].x = wRect.left + rand() % c;
        WPt[0].x = wRect.bottom + rand() % 5 - c;
        PlgBlt(hdc, wPt, hdc, wRect.left, wRect.bottom - wRect.right, wRect.left, wRect.bottom - wRect.top, 0, 0, 0,);
Sleep(300); 
}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Can you provide relevant error messages

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't pay attention to details when do copy/paste.

1. You used the same element of WPt array
2. You used only x component

There are also many other mistakes: different names of WPt, wPt, WPT, excessive comma in the end of the call to PlgBlt, etc.

Have a fun with this:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {

HDC hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
POINT WPT[3];
RECT wRect;
int x = GetSystemMetrics(0), y = GetSystemMetrics(1);

while (TRUE)
{
    int c = 10
        ;GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &wRect);
    WPT[0].x = wRect.left + rand() % 21 - 11;
    WPT[0].y = wRect.bottom + rand() % 21 - 11;
    WPT[1].x = wRect.right + rand() % 21 - 11;
    WPT[1].y = wRect.top + rand() % 10 - 5;
    WPT[2].x = wRect.left + rand() % c;
    WPT[2].y = wRect.bottom + rand() % 5 - c;   
    PlgBlt(hdc, WPT, hdc, wRect.left, wRect.bottom - wRect.right, wRect.left, wRect.bottom - wRect.top, 0, 0, 0);
    Sleep(300);
}
}
```

And stop making viruses, even for joke. Do something useful from the beginning.